# Is the Proof of Gisin's Theorem Wrong?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

I have been trying to understand Gisin's paper, *[Bell's inequality holds for all non-product states](https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(91)90805-I)*. As I've worked through the proof he provides for his theorem, I've run into two things that simply seem wrong. Can someone please clarify either by showing me where I'm making a mistake or confirming that his paper is wrong? I list my concerns below.

**First**, Gisin states the theorem assuming $$P(a, b) = \langle (2a-1) \otimes (2b-1) \rangle_\psi, $$ but never specifies what $a$ and $b$ are. He calls them *projectors*, which seemingly implies $a = | a \rangle \langle a | = \mathbf{a} (\mathbf{a}^\dagger)$, $b = | b \rangle \langle b | = \mathbf{b} (\mathbf{b}^\dagger)$. But then $(2a-1) \otimes (2b-1)$ is a 9x9 matrix, while $\psi$ is (presumably) 4D, making the calculation of $\langle (2a-1) \otimes (2b-1) \rangle_\psi = \mathbf{\psi}^\dagger [(2a-1) \otimes (2b-1)] \mathbf{\psi}$ impossible.

Replacing $\rho$ with $\psi^*\psi$ in Bell's definition of $P$ (equation 2 in his paper *[On the Einstein Podolsky Rosen Paradox](https://cds.cern.ch/record/111654/files/vol1p195-200_001.pdf)*), we get $$P(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) = \int \psi^*(\lambda) A(\mathbf{a}, \lambda) B(\mathbf{b}, \lambda) \psi(\lambda) \,d\lambda\,, $$  similar to the analytic expression for the expectation value of the spin correlation operator (sorry if that's not what it's actually called—I don't know it's *official* name). In bra-ket notation it would be $$P(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) = \langle (\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}) \otimes (\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}) \rangle_\psi. $$ Using this expression for $P$ instead of the one Gisin provides I can follow most of the proof, and the fact that he himself mentions this value on page 202 (though in a context that seems unrelated to $P$) is a hint that maybe this is what he intended. But then his proof doesn't actually prove his theorem (involving $P = \langle (2a-1) \otimes (2b-1) \rangle$)—it proves a similar theorem involving $P = \langle (\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}) \otimes (\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}) \rangle$. So what are $a$, $a'$, $b$, and $b'$? Are they supposed to relate to $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}$ and $\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}$? Why does he use $2a-1$ and $2b-1$?

**Second**, Gisin states, as the final step of his proof, that $$|P(a, b) - P(a, b')| + P(a', b) + P(a', b') = 2(1+4|c_1 c_2|)^{-\frac{1}{2}} > 2.$$ However, for all values of $c_1$ and $c_2$, I get $$2(1+4|c_1 c_2|)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \leq 2.$$ What is going on here?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this not what is normally referred to as Gisin's theorem? I thought when people referred to Gisin's theorem, they meant a no-go theorem for nonlinear quantum mechanics, Gisin, "Weinberg's non-linear quantum mechanics and supraluminal communications," https://www.unige.ch/gap/quantum/publications:bib:gisin1990

Comment: @BenCrowell You could be right. When I have talked about this with my research advisor, he has offhandedly called it Gisin's theorem, so I assumed that was what it was known as. If you have a suggestion for a better title, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I was able to find satisfactory answers to my questions.

**First answer:** I was able to find that the projection operators $a$ and $b$ can be written as $$ a = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{\sigma} ),\quad b = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{\sigma} ), $$ from which easily follows $$ 2a - 1 = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma},\quad 2b - 1 = \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}. $$ Then, $\langle (2a - 1) \otimes (2b - 1) \rangle $ is equivalent to $ \langle \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma} \otimes \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma} \rangle, $ so Gisin's proof *is* consistent with the statement of his theorem.

**Second answer:** Applying the same assumptions as Gisin to relate the vectors $\mathbf{a},$ $\mathbf{a}',$ $\mathbf{b},$ and $\mathbf{b}'$ to the angles $ \alpha, $ $ \alpha', $ $ \beta, $ and $ \beta', $ we have $$ S = |P(a, b) - P(a, b')| + P(a', b) + P(a', b') = |\cos\beta - \cos\beta'| + 2|c_1 c_2|(\sin\beta + \sin\beta'). $$ Using $ \sin\beta = (1 - \cos^2\beta)^{-\frac{1}{2}} $ to solve $ \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} S = 0 $ for $ \cos\beta, $ we see that $S$ is maximized when $$ \cos\beta = -\cos\beta' = (1 + 4|c_1 c_2|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}. $$ Using $ \cos\beta = (1 - \sin^2\beta)^{-\frac{1}{2}} $ to solve this equation for $ \sin\beta $ and $ \sin\beta', $ we obtain $$ \sin\beta = \sin\beta' = \Bigg(1 + \frac{1}{1 + 4|c_1 c_2|^2}\Bigg)^{-\frac{1}{2}} $$ $$ \implies S = \frac{2}{(1 + 4|c_1 c_2|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}} + 4|c_1 c_2|\Bigg(1 - \frac{1}{1 + 4|c_1 c_2|^2}\Bigg)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 2(1 + 4|c_1 c_2|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} > 2. $$ This final expression differs from Gisin's result by a power of $-1$ outside the parentheses and a power of $2$ inside. This looks like it's just a typo on Gisin's part.